# When is Darcy's law valid

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I've read that [Darcy's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%27s_law) is valid at a “great distance” from the free flow. What does this mean? and what is the alternative equation to be used in the cases when Darcy's equation doesn't apply?

Comment: In the article to which you link it only says that Darcy's law is valid if the flow is laminar through the porous medium.